# Random Error for opening CSV files with Google Sheets Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My issue concerns the openning of CSV files into Google Sheet with Apps Scripts.
My code works but randomly, sometimes I got the following error message : " Exception: Service timed out: Spreadsheets at writeDataToSheet(Open_Files:17:53)".

I know it is an exception but it breaks the writing of CSV files. Do you have any idea to avoid this exception ?

This is my code right below:

```
//Function which finds all the files contained in the folder from Google Drive
function findFilesInDrive() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("ImpactFilesCSV");
  var fold = folder.next();
  var files = fold.getFiles();
  var result = [];
  while (files.hasNext())
    result.push(files.next());
  return result;
}

//Inserts a new sheet and writes a 2D array of data in it
function writeDataToSheet(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet = ss.insertSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  // sheetName = sheet.getRange("A10").getValues();
  // sheet.setName(sheetName);
  return //sheet.getName();
}

function OpenFiles(files) {
  for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i]; //i for the loop
    // var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Retrieving the CSV file under a string
    var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()); //separating the strings
    writeDataToSheet(contents);
    sheetName = sheet.getRange("A10").getValues();
    // sheetName.slice(0,sheetName.length-1)
    sheet.setName(sheetName);
    // sheet.getRange('A15:A10172').splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.SPACE); //formating the tarjectories for their use
  }
}


function Open(){
  var files = findFilesInDrive();
  OpenFiles(files);

}
```

Comment: Looks like your script excess runtime limitation (6 min): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas . Could you confirm it? Does it run for about 6 min?

Comment: Yes it exceeds the runtime of 6 min, but I have about 30min thanks to the paid workspace account. And how can we explain that the code have already worked ?

Comment: You can use a try catch to capture the errors and collection a little informat on each error so that you can go back to the data to see if it's a data structure issue and then you can continue with the next one.

Comment: Are you sure about 30 min for paid accounts? From the table 'quotas' it looks like everyone has the 6 min limit. But even if you have the 30 min limit I'd consider to change the algorithm in the way to make it to run and stop after some time or some number of steps, save intermediate results, then run it again (manually or via trigger) and resume the work. But this is a tricky task.

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this:

```
function findFilesInDrive() {
  const folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("ImpactFilesCSV");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("CSVLogger");
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(["Error", "FileName"]);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = folders.next();
    let files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.CSV);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      try {
        let csvA = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
        let s = ss.insertSheet();
        s.getRange(1,1,csvA.length,csvA[0].length).setValues(csvA);
      }
      catch (e) {
        sh.appendRow([e, file.getName()]);
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your script and it doesn't solve the issue, first; the execution was completed in 18 minutes and for another try it breaks with the same exception "Service timed out"...

Comment: You should consider doing it in batches